# CALayer shadow issue in ios 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, ios10, xcode8

I Had created a view with corner radius and layer shadow like following image, It was working fine till i build it for ios 9.3.5(xcode 7)

### output build in xcode 7.3 for iOS 9.3.5

[image]

and now as i updated my xcode to 8.0 for ios 10 so shadow for laye and corner radius is not working properly and giving output as below image

### output build in xcode 8 for iOS 10

[image]

I had used following code with autolayout

[image]

I had used following code to achieve that :

```
/*
 * for bottom line in Email text field
 */
CALayer *emailBottomBorder = [CALayer layer];
UIColor *customGrayColor = ACT_COLOR_GRAY;
emailBottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, _emailOutlet.superview.frame.size.height, _emailOutlet.superview.frame.size.width, 1.0f);
emailBottomBorder.backgroundColor = customGrayColor.CGColor;
[_emailOutlet.superview.layer addSublayer:emailBottomBorder];

/*
 * for bottom line in Email text field
 */
CALayer *passwordBottomBorder = [CALayer layer];
passwordBottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, _passwordOutlet.superview.frame.size.height, _passwordOutlet.superview.frame.size.width, 1.0f);
passwordBottomBorder.backgroundColor = customGrayColor.CGColor;
[_passwordOutlet.superview.layer addSublayer:passwordBottomBorder];

/*
 * for box corner radius
 */
CALayer *layer = _boxView.layer;
layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;

/*
 * for box layer shadow
 */
layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,3);
layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
layer.shadowRadius = 8.0f;
layer.shadowOpacity = 0.50f;
layer.shadowPath = [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:layer.bounds] CGPath];

/*
 * for signinContainerView (inner view) corner radius (top-left and top-right)
 */
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:_signinContainerView.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
maskLayer.path  = maskPath.CGPath;
_signinContainerView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Anyone please guide me on solving this shadow and corner radius issue

Comment: In what method (e.g. viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear) is the above code called? Check in the debugger, if `self.view.bound` has the correct values or (0, 0, 1000, 1000). Possibly, you call the code too early when layout hasn't finished yet.

Comment: @Codo, I have used in viewDidLoad. it was working properly in earlier version 9.3.5 (xcode 7.3)

Comment: Then `self.view.bounds` will have invalid values as the layout isn't completed until `viewDidAppear` is called. Move the code for the shadow to `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: @Codo, Thank you....you are absolutely right...bounds value is (0,0,1000,1000)

Comment: @Codo, since i moved my code into `viewDidAppear` it is working fine. :) But I have a question here as i moved my code to `viewDidAppear `so code will get execute whenever view appear??? don't you think it will add so many layers in view? will it be good if i add some flag in `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: Yes, you should make sure it's only run once. Or remove he previous layers when it's run more than once.

Comment: @Codo, Thank you so much. :) i'm wondering, Why apple has done in xcode 8...as if we are using such case we need to save so many flags. :(